# Laravel: Generate random unique token

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have a table in my database called `keys` that has this structure:

```
id | user_id | token_id | token_key
```

Every time a user logs into my site, I need to generate a new `token_id` and `token_key` set for that user. How can I generate a random token for both the `token_id` and the `token_key` while keeping the two values unique?

For example, if:

- `token_id` is `dfbs98641aretwsg`,
- `token_key` is `sdf389dxbf1sdz51fga65dfg74asdf`

Meaning:

```
id | user_id | token_id         | token_key
1  | 1       | dfbs98641aretwsg | sdf389dxbf1sdz51fga65dfg74asdf
```

There can be no other row in the table with that combination of tokens. How can I do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'd avoid including an extra package for a case like this one. Something like:

```
do {
    $token_id = makeRandomToken();
    $token_key = makeRandomTokenKey();
} while (User::where("token_id", "=", $token_id)->where("token_key", "=", $token_key)->first() instanceof User);
```

...should do. Replace model name with yours, if different from 'User', and use your or suggested functions for creating random strings.

Comment: Can you explain how the while loop will guarantee there won't be any duplicates?

Comment: More specifically, what does `instanceof` do in the while loop?

Comment: [`do-while`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php) loop will keep "doing" as long as the statement in "while" evaluates as `true` (and it will run at least once, unlike `while-do`). In this specific example, it will generate token id/key pair, then it will try to find a user in database that has that specific token and key pair. `instanceof` checks if the result is instance of the `User` class, meaning that it's checking if such user is found. If it is, `do` will execute again and make another pair, and so on until it finds no user having the generated pair of token id/key.

Comment: This is a very bad solution! You should never wish to loop through every record in you database table each time you want to add a new record. You should better use a time based unique string.

Comment: It is *not* looping through *every* record in the table each time a new record is added. Please try understanding the `do-while` loop.

Comment: I agree with @Marten. Not a good solution. There are two things wrong with it: First you hit the database every time you create a new token at least once - if the token exists in the db, you hit it again. Second, there is no guarantee of uniqueness. The same key can be inserted into the db by another thread right after you check for its existence and before you insert it on the current thread. Why not use UUID's, which have a high degree of safety when it comes to uniqueness?

Comment: @Marten I assumed that the author already has methods for generating strings and that the problem is making sure that those *key/token pairs* do not exist in the database already. We can talk about uniqueness until tomorrow :) Also, the database is "hit" only when a successful login happens, but I'll be glad to look into its performance issue free of charge if this particular query surfaces becomes one in OP's app.

Comment: One possible improvement would be to just try to insert the new tokens instead of SELECTing them. If they're not unique request will fail (assuming the DB is correctly set with unique indices), and you go back into the loop and create a new pair and try again until the operation succeeds. This would guarantee the atomicity of the operation.

Answer (score 25):

In terms of generating the tokens, you could use one of [Laravel's Helper Functions](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-str-random); `str_random()`.

This will generate a random string of a specified length, e.g `str_random(16)` will generate a random string of 16 characters (upper case, lower case, and numbers).

Depending on how you are using the tokens, do they really need to be completely unique? Given that they will match to a user, or I assume you may be using the `token_id` and then verifying this against the `token_key` does it really matter if there is a double up of one of them? - although the chances of this are extremely small!

However, if you do need them to be truly unique you can always use a validator with the `unique` constraint. Using [this package](https://github.com/felixkiss/uniquewith-validator) you could also test that the two of them are unique too with `unique_with`. And then if the validator fails then it generates a new token as needed.

Based off your examples, you would be using `str_random(16)` for `token_id` and `str_random(30)` for the `token_key`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dependency to do this. [Dirape laravel-token](https://github.com/Dirape/laravel-token)

Run the command

```
composer require dirape/token
```

In your controller use

```
use Dirape\Token\Token;
```

You can use it like this:

```
User::create([
        'name'             => $data['name'],
        'email'            => $data['email'],
        'password'         => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'token_key' => (new Token())->Unique('users', 'api_token', 60),
        'active'           => 1
    ])
```

Answer (score 1):

Following @ivanhoe suggestion... this is what I came up with:-

```
    $token = new Token;

    //in case there are duplicate
    for ($x = 0; $x < 10; $x ++) {
        $token->access_token = str_random(16);;
        try {
            if ($token->save()) {
                break;
            }
        }catch (QueryException $e) {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is better:

```php
do {
    $this->slug = strtolower(str()->random(5));
} while (User::where("slug", $this->slug)->exists());
```

Answer (score -1):

For other users seeing this post. Best solution I found was using another string or intiger to make a token. for example what is doing laravel when creating a new user.

```
base64_encode($data['email']); // here using the email as base
```